# Create ViewContainerRef object in angular Utility class

Tags: javascript, angular, user-interface

In one of my scenario I have moved duplicate Angular component code to one Utility class and I am re-using the logic by calling the method in all the components.

In that Utility file logic I am using ViewContainerRef and I am executing javscript code at runtime.

Like below I have multiple components and re-using logic from Utility class in all the components.
Here I am getting below error. After some research I came know that ViewContainerRef can be used only in Component or as a Directive.

Could some one please help how do I instantiate ViewContainerRef object in Utility class.

Error Message.

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgIf -> ViewContainerRef]:
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgIf -> ViewContainerRef]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for ViewContainerRef!
```

Component class

```
import {ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'dz-page-1',
  templateUrl: './component-page-1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-page-1.component.scss']
})

export class ContentInspectPageComponent{
constructor(protected viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,){
handleMenuAction(event){
let customUtilHandler = new CustomUtilHandler(this.viewContainerRef);
return customUtilHandler.handleCustomForm();
}
}
}
```

Utility Class

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomUtilHandler {
constructor( protected viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef){
}
handleCustomForm(){
this.viewContainerRef.clear();
const component = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent("customComponent");
component.instance["data"] = inputData;
}
}
```

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using Angular dependency injection for your service?

Comment: Here one is the Component class and other is Utility class (service). I am calling Utility class method from Component class method by instantiating through the constructor. I am using dependency injection let customUtilHandler = new CustomUtilHandler(this.viewContainerRef);

Comment: That’s not DI . I’d expect private utilHandler: CustomUtilHandler in the constructor.

Comment: ha ha :) got it. Because I have to instantiate service class by calling the service class constructor by passing the required parameters.

Comment: My issue got resolved with below solution, thank you very much @MikeOne https://stackoverflow.com/a/55471492/4128499