# How to create dynamic components using service without ComponentFactoryResolver as it is deprecated in angular

Tags: angular, dynamic-components

As you may know in earlier versions of angular, dynamic components could be created with the help of `ComponentFactoryResolver` as

```
export class DialogService {
  dialogComponentRef: ComponentRef<DialogComponent>

  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private appRef: ApplicationRef,
    private injector: Injector
  ) {}

  appendDialogComponentToBody() {
     // logic to add component using `ComponentFactoryResolver` instance
  }
}
```

but now `ComponentFactoryResolver` is deprecated for latest versions.

Yeah there is a way (so far I know) we can create dynamic components with the following snippet

```
@ViewChild("viewContainerRef", { read: ViewContainerRef }) vcr!: ViewContainerRef;
```

but again this only works within the `component`, not with `service`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I inject ViewContainerRef into a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636840/how-can-i-inject-viewcontainerref-into-a-service)

Comment: As long as you stay in Angular 13, it's okay to keep using the "deprecated way". The replacement is only available in 14.1 Please have a look here https://netbasal.com/getting-to-know-the-createcomponent-api-in-angular-22fb115f08e2 The new createComponent API, that's the replacement.

Comment: @shrink actually your provided is required to have component already exist but think of an angular material dialog, you just create the dialog-component only through a service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use the `createComponent` function exported from `@angular/core`,

```
const componentRef = createComponent(MyComponent, {
  environmentInjector: this.appRef.injector,
})
```

then

```
this.appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView); // and detach later
```

and you should be good to go without `viewContainerRef`

[Docs](https://angular.io/api/core/createComponent)

Comment: should appRef.injector fail, that means it doesn't have all providers. In that case take the injector from the target component.

Comment: Amazing, I was wondering how to do this without needing `ViewContainerRef`. Didn't know they exported such a simple function to do this now